# combine and append dataframe as list of dictionarys to a response object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe in below format:

| daily_dates | registered | attended |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02/10/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/09/2022 | 0 | 0 |
| 02/08/2022 | 1 | 0 |

And my `response` object is of this format:

```
response = {"registered":[], "attended":[]}
```

I am looking to combine `daily_dates` with `registered` and `attended` column to result in below `response` object.

```
response = {"registered":[{"02/10/2022":0},{"02/09/2022":0},{"02/08/2022":1}], "attended":[{"02/10/2022":0},{"02/09/2022":0},{"02/08/2022":0}]}
```

The below is my current coding approach:

```
weekly['registered'] = weekly.apply(lambda row: {row['daily_dates']: row['registered']}, axis=1)
response["registered"] += weekly['registered'].tolist()
```

I am looking for a much efficient and direct way of achieving this.

Answer (score 0):

Direct but ugly:

```
response = {"registered":[], "attended":[]}
for _, d, r, a in weekly.itertuples(name=None):
    response['registered'].append({d: r})
    response['attended'].append({d: a})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can build it manually like this:

#### Option 1:

```
dd = df.set_index('daily_dates').to_dict()
for k in dd.keys():
  l = []
  for ki, v in dd[k].items():
      l.append({ki: v})
  dd[k] = l
dd
```

Output:

```
{'registered': [{'02/10/2022': 0}, {'02/09/2022': 0}, {'02/08/2022': 1}],
 'attended': [{'02/10/2022': 0}, {'02/09/2022': 0}, {'02/08/2022': 0}]}
```

#### Option 2 using defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
defd = defaultdict(list)

dd = df.set_index('daily_dates').to_dict()
[defd[k].append({ek:ev}) for k, v in dd.items() for ek, ev in v.items()]
dict(defd)
```

Output:

```
{'registered': [{'02/10/2022': 0}, {'02/09/2022': 0}, {'02/08/2022': 1}],
 'attended': [{'02/10/2022': 0}, {'02/09/2022': 0}, {'02/08/2022': 0}]}
```